# Estimating the weight of a vehicle moving in a highway

Tags: kinematics, weight

I need to know the estimated weight of a truck in a highway without using scales.

What do I have?

- Speed of the car at time X
- RPM at time X
- horse power
- Estimated distance from a point A to B (calculated from GPS data)
- And everything I can get from the computer of the car

If you need another variable feel free to ask if I can get it.

I may also know the default weight of the car from the manual but this is not something to be sure.

I started with this simple formula: $F=ma$ OR $m=F/a$, but this is with a constant acceleration and I can't be sure of that.

What if we take the problem as 'I want to know the mass of an object in movement, with a non-constant acceleration', or something more neutral. What variables do I need to know? What laws of physics can help?

Comment: How accurate an estimate do you need?  An order of magnitude? Within a factor of two? Within 10%? Within 1%?

Comment: Within 10% if possible

Comment: If you mean to just watch it go by without making any measurement, you are probably out of luck. If you can make a measurement that does not use a scale, it depends on what you are willing to accept. Calibrate a tow truck and see how fast it can be towed off? The easiest way would be to ask the driver.

Comment: Maybe you did not notice @puma91, I have changed my answer since I found something you might like.

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer seems to be misleading as I found a way to calculate what you asked by the measurements you said you can take!

Assuming that the weight is equally distributed on each tyre, we can equate the torque due to friction with angular acceleration of tyre multiplies by moment of inertia of tyre. The equations would be as following: 
$$ I_{tyre} \alpha = \frac {\mu m g }{4R} $$
$$ m = \frac {4 \alpha I_{tyre}}{\mu g R} $$
$$ m = \frac {4 I_{tyre} ({\omega}_f - {\omega}_i)}{\mu g R t} $$
$$ m = \frac {4 I_{tyre} (v_f - v_i)}{\mu g R^2 t} $$

You can use either the last or second-last equation for a good approximation, there $\omega $ cqn be calculated using rpm, $ t $ is the time between two measurements, $\mu $ is the coefficient of friction between tyre and road, $ R $ is radius of tyre and $ I_{tyre} $ is moment of inertia of tyre.

Comment: What if we take the problem as 'I want to know the mass of an object in movement, with a non-constant acceleration', or something more neutral. What variables do I need to know? What laws of physics can help?

Comment: Well I am sad to say that either there are none, or I know none. The answer I gave you is as close I could get to getting mass from a moving object from the variables measured in a vehicles computer. There seems to be simply no possible way to extract mass from a combination of velocity, distance, rpm etc!

Comment: If you could somehow (I dont think its possible) get the energy difference of car over a small difference where potential energy of car remains same along with velocity both initial and final, then it is possible. I thought of many ways to get this energg difference but there are too many uncalculable factors such as land and air friction, heat loses, AC use, stereo use, battery consumption, different rate of fuel consumption, different efficiency of engine at different velocities that it turned out to be just impossible to calculate!

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm going to test this formula and tell you how well it went.